# How to remove a certain amount of something from someone's inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In a map I am making, to enter a certain place someone must have 3 iron ingots to enter. I've tried using the `/clear` command, but if they have more than 3 they lose it all. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What is the full command you are using, including arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve it with clear by adding a maxCount

```
clear [player] [item] [data] [maxCount] [dataTag]
```

So it should be

```
/clear @p minecraft:iron_ingot -1 3
```

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/clear [player] [item] [maxCount]`, co `/clear @p minecraft:iron_ingot 3`